# The problem with importing Product Sheet in the category, the title that has a comma

Tags: magento2, import, csv

When importing faced such problem. If the path search has regular commas after each comma creates a new category.
Example:
Default Category/Event,Music and Image/

need to create a single category("Event,Music and Image"),but it turns out several categories^
1) event
2)Music and image.

tell me how to import category with a comma?